# Alignment of overflowing rotated \parbox

Tags: floats, layout, parbox

I am looking to achieve the following within a `figure`:

- A main graphics element which occupies the full `\linewidth`
- Rotated text labels on the left and on the right, vertically centered with graphics, and placed outside of the main page width (i.e. overflowing on the left and right margins).

I've gotten close with the MWE below. It works exactly as I'd like for the left rotated text, but there are two problems with the right label:

1. It seems to be wrongly anchored vertically. I found that surrounding it with `\frame` places it back at the right location, but I don't want the frame to be visible.
2. It occupies some space within the main page width, despite using the same `\makebox[0pt]` as the left label. Because of this, I had to reduce the width of the image in my MWE to less than `\linewidth`.

I realize this is probably not the best way to achieve my goals, but I'd be grateful for any help with these issues (if possible not involving any new packages).

---

[image: MWE: correct placement, but only with \frame]

[image: MWE: incorrect placement when not using \frame]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Without indent, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \makebox[0pt][r]{
        \rotatebox{90}{
            \parbox{7.20cm}{\centering Left label: working well without frame.}
        }
    }
    \includegraphics[height=7.20cm]{example-image-golden}
    \frame{  % <-- How to avoid this?
        \makebox[0pt][t]{
            \rotatebox{-90}{
                \parbox{7.20cm}{\centering Right label \textbf{with frame}: working.}
            }
        }
    }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \makebox[0pt][r]{
        \rotatebox{90}{
            \parbox{7.20cm}{\centering Left label: working well without frame.}
        }
    }
    \includegraphics[height=7.20cm]{example-image-golden}
    \makebox[0pt][t]{
        \rotatebox{-90}{
            \parbox{7.20cm}{\centering Right label \textbf{without frame}: not working.}
        }
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use `\smash` and `\llap`/`\rlap`, and use the `origin=` setting for `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]% dummy text

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \smash{\llap{%
        \rotatebox{90}{
            \parbox{7.20cm}{\centering Left label: working well without frame.}
        }
    }}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-golden}%
    \smash{\ \rlap{%
        \rotatebox[origin=br]{-90}{
            \parbox{7.20cm}{\centering Right label \textbf{without frame}: working.}
        }
    }}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated labels example]

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you for taking the time! Out of curiosity, how do you decide when to include `%` before a line break?

Comment: I honestly can't remember why I put those in, or know whether they're necessary, but basically I put them in when it looks like there's a space I wasn't expecting; I don't try to memorize a set of rules of when or when not to do it. Maybe others can do that, but I can't.